# How to move character in two speeds without one affecting the other?

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-development

OK, so this is a little hard to explain. I'm making a canvas-based point-and-click 2d game. You can look around (move the environment) by dragging the mouse horizontally across the screen. And move the character by clicking where you want him to go. Kinda like This War of Mine. Here's a simplified version of what I got...

MOUSE ACTIONS:

```
var held, mouseX, mouseXInitial;
window.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
    held = true;
    mouseXInitial = mouseX; 
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
    held = false;
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    mouseX = e.clientX;
});
mouseEvents();
```

LOOKING AROUND (dragging across the screen to look around the environment):

```
var sharedParentObject = {
    scrolledAmount: null,
    scrolling: function(){
        if (held){
            this.scrolledAmount = mouseX - mouseXInitial;
            this.x = this.xInitial + this.scrolledAmount;
        }
    },
    inputShared: function(){
        var that = this;
        window.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
            that.xInitial = that.x;
        });
        window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            that.scrolling();
        });
    }
}
```

MOVING THE CHARACTER:

```
 function Character(){
    this.speed = 2;
    this.target = null;
    this.input = function(){
        var that = this;
        window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
            that.target = that.mouseXInitial;
            that.target += that.scrolledAmount;
        });
    }
    this.update = function(){
        if (this.target){
            //moving right
            if (this.x + this.w/2 < this.target){
                this.x += this.speed;
            }
            //moving left
            if (this.x + this.w/2 > this.target){
                this.x -= this.speed;
            }
        }
    }
 }

 Character.prototype = Object.create(sharedParentObject);
```

This works but the problem is that once I start dragging across the screen to look around, while the character is already walking, it gets all weird and jittery. I understand why this is happening. The character's x is getting changed in both the character class and the parent class at the same time. Is there a way to have it so the character can keep walking towards the target, while still getting moved as I scroll the environment? Kinda doing both, without one affecting the other..

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - Perhaps some debounce is needed

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is track the distance the mouse have moved between the onmousedown and onmouseup events. If the distance is very small, then the user has clicked on one spot, if the distance is larger then they are trying to pan the scene.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // ES5 Friendly class functions
  // (Supports overloading & single inheritance)
  var _class = (function() {
  
   "use strict";
   
   /*
    All a class is in JS is a function that
    acts as a constructor and an object (prototype)
    that holds the properties shared across all
    instances (static vars, constants & functions).
   */
   
   function _class(constructor,prototype) {
    prototype.base = null;
    prototype.super = constructor;
    
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    
    return constructor;
   }
   
   _class.extends = function(base,constructor,prototype) {
    for (var property in base.prototype) {
     if (!prototype[property]) {
      prototype[property] = base.prototype[property];
     }
    }
    
    function bundledConstructor() {
     base.apply(this,arguments);
     constructor.apply(this,arguments);
    }
    
    prototype.base = base;
    prototype.super = bundledConstructor;
    
    bundledConstructor.prototype = prototype;
    
    return bundledConstructor;
   }
   
   return _class;
  
  })();
  
  void function() {
   
   "use strict";
   
   // Classes
   
   // Encapsulate canvas element
   var Viewport = _class(
    function(canvasID,width,height,bgColour) {
     this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID) || null;
     this.width = width || 1.0;
     this.height = height || 1.0;
     this.bgColour = bgColour || "gray";
     this.hWidth = this.width >> 1;
     this.hHeight = this.height >> 1;
     this.canvas.width = this.width;
     this.canvas.height = this.height;
     this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
     this.ctx.translate(this.hWidth,this.hHeight);
     
     var bounds = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
     
     this.leftMargin = bounds.left;
     this.topMargin = bounds.top;
    },{
     clear: function() {
      var ctx = this.ctx;
      ctx.fillStyle = this.bgColour;
      ctx.fillRect(-this.hWidth,-this.hHeight,this.width,this.height);
     }
    }
   );
   
   // This is a class used to encapsulate
   // the scene's panning/zooming.
   var Camera = _class(
    // Constructor Function
    function(viewport,x,y) {
     this.viewport = viewport || null;
     this.x = x || 0.0;
     this.y = y || 0.0;
     this.scale = 1.0;
     this.invScale = 1.0 / this.scale;
     
     this.allowUserInput = false;
     this.mouseDown = false;
     this.mouseLastX = 0.0;
     this.mouseLastY = 0.0;
     
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("wheel",this.onwheel.bind(this));
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",this.onmousedown.bind(this));
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",this.onmouseup.bind(this));
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",this.onmousemove.bind(this));
    },
    
    // Prototype (constant values & functions go here)
    { 
     scaleCoordinates: function(x,y) {
      return [
       (x - this.viewport.hWidth) * this.invScale + this.x,
       (y - this.viewport.hHeight) * this.invScale + this.y
      ];
     },
     
     scaleDimensions: function(width,height) {
      return [
       width * this.invScale,
       height * this.invScale
      ];
     },
     
     pan: function(deltaX,deltaY) {
      this.x += deltaX;
      this.y += deltaY;
     },
     
     zoom: function(deltaScale) {
      this.scale += deltaScale;
      this.scale = Math.max(0.0,this.scale);
      this.invScale = 1.0 / this.scale;
     },
     
     onwheel: function(e) {
      if (this.allowUserInput) {
       var deltaY = -Math.sign(e.deltaY) * (e.deltaY / e.deltaY) * 0.25;
       
       this.zoom(deltaY);
      }
     },
     
     onmousedown: function(e) {
      this.mouseDown = true;
      
      [
       this.mouseLastX,
       this.mouseLastY
      ] = this.scaleCoordinates(
       e.clientX - this.viewport.leftMargin,
       e.clientY - this.viewport.topMargin
      );
     },
     
     onmouseup: function(e) {
      this.mouseDown = false;
     },
     
     onmousemove: function(e) {
      if (this.allowUserInput && this.mouseDown) {
       var [
        mouseX,
        mouseY
       ] = this.scaleCoordinates(
        e.clientX - this.viewport.leftMargin,
        e.clientY - this.viewport.topMargin
       );
       
       this.pan(
        this.mouseLastX - mouseX,
        this.mouseLastY - mouseY
       );
      }
     }
    }
   );
   
   // Contains basic behaviour all game objects will have
   var GameObject = _class(
    function(x,y,width,height,colour) {
     this.x = x || 0.0;
     this.y = y || 0.0;
     this.width = width || 1.0;
     this.height = height || 1.0;
     this.colour = colour || "darkblue";
     this.dx = 0.0;
     this.dy = 0.0;     
     this._draw_x = 0.0;
     this._draw_y = 0.0;
     this._draw_width = 0.0;
     this._draw_height = 0.0;
    },{
     updateDrawParameters: function(camera) {
      this._draw_width = this.width * camera.scale;
      this._draw_height = this.height * camera.scale;
      this._draw_x = ((this.x - camera.x) * camera.scale) - this._draw_width * 0.5;
      this._draw_y = ((this.y - camera.y) * camera.scale) - this._draw_height * 0.5;
     },
     
     tick: function() {
      
     },
     
     render: function(viewport) {
      var ctx = viewport.ctx;
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this._draw_x,this._draw_y,this._draw_width,this._draw_height);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
     }
    }
   );
   
   // A more specialized type of game object that
   // can move to a specific location
   var MoveAgent = _class.extends(GameObject,
    function(x,y,width,height,colour) {
     this.currentState = this.STATE_IDLE;
     this.targetX = 0.0;
     this.targetY = 0.0;
    },{
     STATE_IDLE: 1000,
     STATE_MOVING_TO_TARGET: 1001,
     
     MOVE_SPEED: 1.0,
     GOAL_TOLERANCE: 5.0, // How close is 'good enough' to the target
     
     moveTo: function(x,y) {
      this.targetX = x || 0.0;
      this.targetY = y || 0.0;
      this.currentState = this.STATE_MOVING_TO_TARGET;
     },
     
     tick: function() {
      switch(this.currentState) {
       case this.STATE_IDLE:
        
       break;
       
       case this.STATE_MOVING_TO_TARGET:
        var x = this.targetX - this.x;
        var y = this.targetY - this.y;
        var l = x * x + y * y;
        
        if (l < this.GOAL_TOLERANCE * this.GOAL_TOLERANCE) {
         this.currentState = this.STATE_IDLE;
        } else {
         l = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(l);
         this.dx = x * l * this.MOVE_SPEED;
         this.dy = y * l * this.MOVE_SPEED;
         this.x += this.dx;
         this.y += this.dy;
        }
       break;
      }
     }
    }
   );
   
   var ControlledMoveAgent = _class.extends(MoveAgent,
    function(x,y,width,height,colour,camera) {
     this.camera = camera || null;
     
     this.mouseDown = false;
     this.mouseX = 0.0;
     this.mouseY = 0.0;
    
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",this.onmousedown.bind(this));
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",this.onmouseup.bind(this));
     viewport.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",this.onmousemove.bind(this));
    },{
     MOVE_TOLLERANCE: 5.0,
    
     onmousedown: function(e) {
      if (e.button === 0) {
       this.mouseDown = true;
       this.mouseX = e.clientX;
       this.mouseY = e.clientY;
      }
     },
     
     onmouseup: function(e) {
      if (e.button === 0 && this.mouseDown) {
       this.mouseDown = false;
       
       var x = e.clientX - this.camera.viewport.leftMargin;
       var y = e.clientY - this.camera.viewport.topMargin;
       
       [x,y] = this.camera.scaleCoordinates(x,y);
       
       this.moveTo(x,y);
      }
     },
     
     onmousemove: function(e) {
      if (this.mouseDown) {
       var x = this.mouseX - e.clientX;
       var y = this.mouseY - e.clientY;
       var l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
       
       if (l > this.MOVE_TOLLERANCE) {
        this.mouseDown = false;
       }
      }
     }
    }
   );
   
   // Vars
   var camera = null;
   var viewport = null;
   var scenery = [];
   var character = null;
   
   // Functions
   function loop() {
    // Tick
    for (var i = 0; i < scenery.length; ++i) {
     scenery[i].updateDrawParameters(camera);
    }
    
    character.tick();
    character.updateDrawParameters(camera);
    
    // Render
    viewport.clear();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < scenery.length; ++i) {
     scenery[i].render(viewport);
    }
    
    character.render(viewport);
    
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   // Entry Point
   onload = function() {
    viewport = new Viewport("canvas",180,160,"gray");
    camera = new Camera(viewport,0,0);
    camera.allowUserInput = true;
    camera.zoom(0.25);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     scenery[i] = new GameObject(
      180 * Math.random() - 90,
      160 * Math.random() - 80,
      10 + Math.random() * 10,
      10 + Math.random() * 10,
      "#" + ((Math.random() * 255) | 0).toString(16)
       + ((Math.random() * 255) | 0).toString(16)
       + ((Math.random() * 255) | 0).toString(16)
     );
    }
    
    character = new ControlledMoveAgent(0,0,10,10,"darkred",camera);
    
    loop();
   }
  }()
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```